# Google Place search API with pageToken returns same record

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-places-api

I'm listing out restaurants, bars and pubs near by I used "pageToken" as I need more place records.

I faced two issues as

## 1 My URL is not accepting | 'pipeline' symbol.

I tried encoding URL but its not working so Just encode | as "%7C" is this correct way?

## 2 I just tied to list outs only restaurant and use next_page_token while calling next time the API to load more records.

My URL is something like

> [https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=19.0176147,72.8561644&rankby=distance&type=restaurant&key=[MY_APP_KEY]&pageToken=CpQCCQEAAPqnEctK9cCPZtPWY8NnnBSyzCwsmO_MsTZBaIUeEkO6g_7rsw97tY-bMsBY0d0Rjw61zD-Peaos4wMVZTe7TrZhB-GVfpr6ya847qB0t1C_2Qgxe3Abur1YmRW_fop0Ro5bwIkxOjMI2Gh19D1IYGPOZ7qqv1oM3B7P4lHZ59yFwXEhMbMZUvQSiuVyoDKQ-FXQB9FMCGkGkbllH9ZzIm-38_XG4ZsFMOYKHhdhp3hkCiLVc8SwLO01t-Bq1emptTQfHUUtXXcCWEFCFClpkJlw0rRnW2fRXuxEy25nFZlqrNxHgcifA6v_xq7Jfb5J5FDTCT4FSurAa1MUXYCPW3fPri-7n9CpZwzZDp7wUOUPEhBByQSF6FAegW_gFyc4Q9PqGhSqewBPNa7pLMTWLFJR94IfhPPqpg](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=19.0176147,72.8561644&rankby=distance&type=restaurant&key=%5BMY_APP_KEY%5D&pageToken=CpQCCQEAAPqnEctK9cCPZtPWY8NnnBSyzCwsmO_MsTZBaIUeEkO6g_7rsw97tY-bMsBY0d0Rjw61zD-Peaos4wMVZTe7TrZhB-GVfpr6ya847qB0t1C_2Qgxe3Abur1YmRW_fop0Ro5bwIkxOjMI2Gh19D1IYGPOZ7qqv1oM3B7P4lHZ59yFwXEhMbMZUvQSiuVyoDKQ-FXQB9FMCGkGkbllH9ZzIm-38_XG4ZsFMOYKHhdhp3hkCiLVc8SwLO01t-Bq1emptTQfHUUtXXcCWEFCFClpkJlw0rRnW2fRXuxEy25nFZlqrNxHgcifA6v_xq7Jfb5J5FDTCT4FSurAa1MUXYCPW3fPri-7n9CpZwzZDp7wUOUPEhBByQSF6FAegW_gFyc4Q9PqGhSqewBPNa7pLMTWLFJR94IfhPPqpg)

But its returning same records on every request, I have verified that pageToken is getting changed in every request.

Can you please let me know where I made mistake?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are passing wrong key **pageToken**. Change it to **pagetoken** and it will work.

Please refer this link for further information: https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search

Comment: Thank you, because of this key miss-match I spend almost 1 hour.